# Is adding a new key or removing a key in a TMap atomic, or does my TMap val need to be a Ref?

Tags: multithreading, scala, concurrency, jvm, stm

I'm using ScalaSTM.

I will have multiple threads (Actors, actually) that need access to a mutable Map of data.  I'm aware that TMap implements each of its key/value pairs as a Ref, so changing the value of an existing key will be implemented as an atomic operation (and therefore, thread-safe).  What I'm not sure about is the addition and removal of keys...  If multiple threads could be adding and removing keys to and from the TMap, should I declare my `TMap` as a `Ref(TMap)` to ensure the atomicity of key additions/removals, or is that taken care of in the implementation of TMap?

Comment: Is this what the `single` function is for that returns a `View` of the collection with a thread-safe iterator?

https://nbronson.github.io/scala-stm/map_snapshots.html